# input text name array - htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

everything works fine on my validation. see my sample below:

```
return [
  'description' => 'required',
];

<input type="text" name="description">
```

but wen i put this textbox in my form. see the code below:

```
<input type="text" name="load[1][load_country_portname]" />
```

the error came up.

```
htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string
```

Please help.

Comment: Yes it definitely does. However none of the code you show us has anything like a `htmlspecialchars()` function call in it anywhere?

Comment: Those errors normally have a filename and a line number associated with them. Are you showing us the right code

Comment: I use the laravel `$this->validate()`. but it works fine until i put a textbox that the name is formatted in array

Comment: I'd bet my money on a htmlspecialchars error being related to the view, not the controller.

Comment: Have you used this post variable in controller or anywhere in blade using {{ }} ??